# Can I get the object from the database, without knowing what type of the object is?

Tags: swift, realm

I have the class `GraphHandler`. Inside of superclass I try to handle restoring the object that was last saved into the database. For this I'm using primaryKey.
The point is that a the time of restoring I don't know yet which type should I expect. So I tried with this:

```
let realm = ClientManager.cacheRealm()
realm.object(ofType: Object.self, forPrimaryKey: "uniqueid")
```

But I get the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception `RLMException`, reason: 'Object type `RealmSwiftObject` is not managed by the Realm. If using a custom `objectClasses` / `objectTypes` array in your configuration, add `RealmSwiftObject` to the list of `objectClasses` / `objectTypes`.'

Im trying to do it a way that the handler don't need to know in advance which type of object was saved last. What can solve this? I think that implementing generics won't do any good to it as I can't be changed on the fly.

Comment: Have you tried using `Any` for the type?

Comment: @RPatel99 have you ever used `Realm`? That couldn't work for various reasons...

Comment: Nope. Thats why I gave my suggestion as a comment :) I'm not familiar with `Realm` but I thought `Any` might work so I might as well suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you call the function `realm.object`, the type of the object needs to be known, since using this function, `realm` is only searching for objects of a specific type. Moreover, the type of `primary key` can be different as well, hence the type of object you are looking for needs to be known before querying `realm`.

Querying all types and filtering afterwards is only not an option at the moment, since `Result` can only store a single type of objects. However, if you really need to query all types using a single query to get the last database entry regardless of what class it had, have a look at [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109#issuecomment-143834756) comment on a related GitHub issue, where `Realm` engineers give some workaround for the issue.

Another workaround you could try is the following: create a `TimeStamps` class, which is managed by `Realm`, has only a single entry in `Realm` and which has a one-to-one relation to each of your other `Realm` classes. The object on the other side of the one-to-one relation would always be the object that you added the last time to `Realm` of that specific class. With this approach, if you are looking for the latest object added to `realm`, you can use a simple query that retrieves the only `TimeStamps` object you have and you can filter for the object added last by filtering the one-to-one relations `TimeStamps` have. Of course for this to work, you need to associate the creation date of your objects with the relationships you are storing in your `TimeStamps` object and update these relationships in each of your `write transactions`.

Comment: I am not sure if the workaround is explained clearly enough, if not, feel free to tell me and I will try to explain better with an example.